# Error on creating new domain class

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails and I have just installed Groovy Grails Tool Suite on Ubuntu and can launch it.  However, following a tutorial when attempting to create a new domain class, I get the following error:

> An internal error occurred during: "create-domain-class".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: hey L :) any more verbosity to that error ? presume this is in GGTS - is there any red markers on the project ? on the bottom tabs there is markers is there anything in that and https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_autobuild.htm as per this screen shot - disable auto build - but the reason i point here is what happens when u run clean option from that menu

Comment: Hello Mr Bad :)
Found the markers and this is what it shows
Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for groovy.lang.GroovyObject. Fix the build path then try building this project Louise first test  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: If you are new to Groovy/Grails, I would avoid using a full blown IDE at first.  Use a simple text editor and the command line.  Not sure if Eclipse support for Groovy is better but my team uses IntelliJ IDEA and it is an excellent Groovy IDE.  Last I tried Groovy in Eclipse, it was not a good experience.

Comment: What version of grails are you using? GGTS is only good for grails versions <3